# how to display image (containing text) with a good quality

Tags: ios, image, text, vector, uiscrollview

I’m new in iOS and trying to make simple app with hierarchy of  viewcontrollers. In the last one I wanna display scrollable image  (which can also be zoomed at least  x1,5), containing some small black and white picture and a piece of text. Initially I planned to make vector image, convert it to .jpg and  use UIScrollView for  displaying. But I found out that .jpg ( approx. 150 KB) didn’t provide a good quality for displaying text. As I have to use a lot of images I don’t want to  increase image size. What is worse I also want it look good on retina display.

Can you recommend a way how to display image, containing text, with enough quality? 
I mean that I don’t want the user see the separate pixels of letters in the text. Just like when you read text in your e-mail in iOS.  Image size should be as small as possible. Planning physical size of image – approx. 5 cm x 15 cm.

Any help much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get good edges you would need to use png not jpg, which will make the image sizes much larger. I have a better suggestion, more code but better solution.

The answer is to not put the text into the image, but to draw it over it in real time.

You would:

- associate text at some coordinate in the image (say a CGRect) with the image
- create a uiimageview subclass that in the drawRect routine, after calling super, draws the text using the NSString categories on UIKit (which let you draw into a context)

To get going on this please create a small one vc project and get the subclass working there, then back port it to your primary project.